# how to get individual values from the output of systemctl status

Tags: python, systemctl

```
[root@localhost etc]# systemctl status blu_av
● blu_av.service - avscan
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/blu_av.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-03-16 16:31:14 IST; 3s ago
 Main PID: 31934 (av)
   CGroup: /system.slice/blu_av.service
           ├─31934 /opt/services/av
           └─31956 /opt/services/av

Mar 16 16:31:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started avscan.
Mar 16 16:31:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting avscan...
```

If the above is the output of my status. I want to retrieve the service name, uptime and status by using a python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try  [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to parse the output. Here is what I used. Please have a look and comment.

```
import subprocess, re

def read_status(service):
    p =  subprocess.Popen(["systemctl", "status",  service], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    output = output.decode('utf-8')

    service_regx = r"Loaded:.*\/(.*service);"
    status_regx= r"Active:(.*) since (.*);(.*)"
    service_status = {}
    for line in output.splitlines():
        service_search = re.search(service_regx, line)
        status_search = re.search(status_regx, line)

        if service_search:
            service_status['service'] = service_search.group(1)
            #print("service:", service)

        elif status_search:
            service_status['status'] = status_search.group(1).strip()
            #print("status:", status.strip())
            service_status['since'] = status_search.group(2).strip()
            #print("since:", since.strip())
            service_status['uptime'] = status_search.group(3).strip()
            #print("uptime:", uptime.strip())

    return service_status

def main():
    service = 'mysql'
    reponse = read_status(service)

    for key in reponse:
        print('{}:{}'.format(key, reponse[key]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
service:mysql.service
status:active (running)
since:Fri 2018-03-16 09:17:57 CET
uptime:6h ago
```

I simply use [this](https://regex101.com/) to check my regular expressions.

Comment: That's awesome!

Answer (score 20):

`systemd` services have a whole list of properties. To get the start time for example; you could run:

```
systemctl show your.service --property=ActiveEnterTimestamp
```

which would give something like:

```
ActiveEnterTimestamp=Fri 2019-05-03 09:35:02 CEST
```

To see the list of all properties; just run

```
systemctl show your.service
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this when you only have a PID and not the unit name?

Answer (score 5):

`systemctl status` has an option [`--output`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#-o) that allows to use the options of [`journalctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl#-o).

Try JSON which could easily be parsed by Python:

```
$ sudo systemctl status --output=json-pretty nginx
```

Comment: The `--output` flag unfortunately only affects the formatting of the journal output displayed after the service status information.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the output from systemctl by using `subprocess.check_output()` and parse it afterwards.

Comment: The interesting step would be the parsing. How would you do this?

Comment: @LutzHorn @user9279273 Just split the output with `\n` as separator and you'll get an array containing every single line of output. Getting the desired information should be easy from there on.